# Prove this: $\mathbb Z[i]/(1+2i)\simeq\mathbb Z_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

$$\mathbb Z[i]/(1+2i)\simeq\mathbb Z_5$$

Help me with this.

Comment: This is not very fair @drhab. I wrote that and you didn't aprove my edit.

Comment: @User2020201 I didn't approve your edit because I was not aware of any edit. Btw, what does it matter?

Comment: I would perhaps get 2 points. @drhab

Comment: @User2020201 I will now and then look for answers that you give. If I find one that is okay then I will upvote. $10>2$. Deal?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the homomorphism $$\phi:\Bbb Z[i]\rightarrow\Bbb Z_5\\a+bi\mapsto a^2+b^2$$

Show that:

- $\ker(\phi)=(1+2i)$
- $\phi$ is surjective